# Gridlayout height based on Label height in recycleview not aligned

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have managed to get the size of a box layout to change based on the corresponding Label height, however, it doesn't line up perfectly and I cannot figure out why.

I have looked at adding offsets but have had no luck since it ended up making the issue worse

Thank you for any help

```
MainInterface:

<MainInterface@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        #font_name: "Nunito-Black.ttf"
        text: "T            R           U             T            H"
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
    GridLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.12
        cols: 4
        Button:
            text: "Menu1"
        Button:
            text: "Menu2"
        Button:
            text: "Menu3"
        Button:
            text: "Menu4"
    PageLayout:
        border: "20dp"
        swipe_threshold: 0.2
        RecycleView:
            viewclass: 'PostGrid'
            scroll_y: 1
            id: rv
            data: app.posts
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                id: box
                default_size: None, None
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                padding: ["10dp", "16dp"]
                spacing: "8dp"
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                key_size: '_size'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Button:
                text: "peni"
            Button:
                text: "tag @ will J"
            Button:
                text: "Input"


<PostGrid@BoxLayout>:
    message_id: -1
    orientation: "horizontal"
    text: ''
    spacing: "10dp"
    #size_hint: self.width, None
    _size: 0, 74
    size: 0, 74
    text_size: None, None
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "10dp"
        size_hint: .1, 1
        size: self.size
        Button:
            text: "UP"
            font_size: "5dp"
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
        Button:
            text: "DOWN"
            font_size: "5dp"
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
        Label:
            text: "test"
            font_size: "5dp"
            size_hint: 1, 0.6
    Label:
        text: root.text
        padding: 5, 5
        size_hint: .9, 1
        #size: self.texture_size
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        text_size: self.width, None
        color: 0,0,0,1
        #text_size: self.width, None
        #size_hint: None, 1
        #size: self.texture_size
        #font_name: "Nunito-Bold.ttf"
        #font_size: "12dp"
        multiline: True
        #size: 1, root.min_height
        
        on_texture_size:
            app.update_message_size(
            root.message_id,
            self.texture_size,
            root.width)

        pos: self.pos

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.texture_size
                radius: [5, 5, 5, 5]
                pos: self.x, self.y
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:0,0.9,0.9,1
            Line:
                width:0.8
                rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
```

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.metrics import dp

class TruthApp(App):
    posts = ListProperty([{'message_id':0, 'text':"testskjhfjksdhfkjshfjshfjkhskjdfhskjdhfkjshfdkjhsjkdfhskjhdfkjshdfjkhzxczxczxczxcxzczxcxsjkdfhjksdhfkjshkjdfhksjdhfjkshdfjkhsdkjhfkjshdfjkshkjfhskjhfkjshfjkshdkjfhskjhfjshfkjshdfjkshdjkfhskjhfkjshfjksdhjfhsjkdhfjkhsdkjfhskjhfjk\ngdgdgd\ndgdgdg\ndgdgdg\ndggdgd",'_size':[0,0] }, {'message_id':1, 'text':"testskjhfjksdhfkjshfjshfjkhskjdfhskjdhfkjshfdkjhsjkdfhskjhjfhskjhfjk,'_size':[0,0]"}])

    def update_message_size(self, message_id, texture_size, max_width):
        #print(self.posts)
        #print("Here")
        self.posts[message_id] = {**self.posts[message_id], '_size':[0, texture_size[1]]}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TruthApp().run()
```

[image]
^ Image showing how the code above runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `viewclass` of `RecycleView` (i.e. `PostGrid`). You set its `height`as such it could not accomodate its children which is supposed to be the minimum height that will place all its children.

Now that's exactly the attr. `minimum_height` does. With this being applied you also don't need `default_size: None, None` (especially the height attr.)

With this and other modifications your `.kv` file should now look like,

```py
MainInterface:

<MainInterface@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        #font_name: "Nunito-Black.ttf"
        text: "T            R           U             T            H"
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
    GridLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.12
        cols: 4
        Button:
            text: "Menu1"
        Button:
            text: "Menu2"
        Button:
            text: "Menu3"
        Button:
            text: "Menu4"
    PageLayout:
        border: "20dp"
        swipe_threshold: 0.2
        RecycleView:
            viewclass: 'PostGrid'
            scroll_y: 1
            id: rv
            data: app.posts
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                id: box
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                padding: ["10dp", "16dp"]
                spacing: "8dp"
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                key_size: '_size'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Button:
                text: "peni"
            Button:
                text: "tag @ will J"
            Button:
                text: "Input"


<PostGrid@BoxLayout>:
    message_id: -1
    orientation: "horizontal"
    text: ''
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    #_size: 0, 74
    height: self.minimum_height
    text_size: None, None
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "10dp"
        size_hint: .1, 1
        Button:
            text: "UP"
            font_size: "5dp"
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
        Button:
            text: "DOWN"
            font_size: "5dp"
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
        Label:
            text: "test"
            font_size: "5dp"
            size_hint: 1, 0.6
    Label:
        text: root.text
        padding: 5, 5
        #size_hint: .9, 1
        #size: self.texture_size
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        text_size: self.width, None
        color: 0,0,0,1
        #text_size: self.width, None
        #size_hint: None, 1
        #size: self.texture_size
        #font_name: "Nunito-Bold.ttf"
        #font_size: "12dp"
        multiline: True
        #size: 1, root.min_height
        
        on_texture_size:
            app.update_message_size(
            root.message_id,
            self.texture_size,
            root.width)

        pos: self.pos

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.texture_size
                radius: [5, 5, 5, 5]
                pos: self.x, self.y
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:0,0.9,0.9,1
            Line:
                width:0.8
                rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
```